# radgridview (telerik winforms) accept numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am trying to have a radgridview with several columns which one of them is phone number and should accept just numbers. This is a part of my code:

```
private void radGridView1_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "column1")
        {
            var editor = e.ActiveEditor as RadTextBoxEditor;
            var element = editor.EditorElement as RadTextBoxEditorElement;

            element.TextBoxItem.KeyPress -= TextBoxItem_KeyPress;

            element.TextBoxItem.KeyPress += TextBoxItem_KeyPress;
        }
    }

    private void TextBoxItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

It works when I first click on one of cells in column1. But when I want to edit one of cells which is selected (without clicking on) if I press any key (even non-digit) it accepts the first key. Apparently the **CellEditorInitialized** is fired after the first keypress, and it is not desired. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [GridViewMaskBoxColumn](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewmaskboxcolumn).

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView from the Telerik UI for WinForms suite offers GridViewMaskBoxColumn. It allows restricted editing of text data. I believe that it would be more suitable for your phone column:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewmaskboxcolumn

You can set a mask to GridViewMaskBoxColumn using its Mask and MaskType properties. You can find further information about the possible values for these properties in RadMaskEditBox documentation section:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/editors/maskededitbox/getting-started
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/editors/maskededitbox/standard-masks

I hope this information helps.